# Chrome extension, iframe, toolbar - hack

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, toolbar

I am working on my extension - toolbar for Google Chrome. It is a rectangle:

```
\#top { width:100%; height:50px; top:0; left:0 }
```

The problem is the only way I know is to inject toolbar's code into iframe. It is fine as in respect to the same origin policy, the websites cannot manipulate the html that is inside the iframe.

**!BUT!**

What if the owners of webpages use the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval('$("#top").hide()',5000);

});
```

Then it just simply hide my toolbar. So is there any solution possible to prevent such manipulations while developing chrome extension?

Comment: You can send me an email for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take something that is less likely to exist in the global namespace, for example:

```
#extension-name-top { width:100%; height:50px; top:0; left:0 }
```

Comment: Ok, but they still can have a look at my extension and check what is the name/id for the top panel.

Comment: If they do so much effort to hide your toolbar perhaps they have reason to do so?

Comment: I would like to connect it with my social website. What if the website would be well known and they will for any reason would like to hide my top panel? Why I don't have (via extension) a possibility to prevent such a manipulation - the user decided to install an extension. It is possible to do so with firefox. Please, have a look at writeonglass.com

Comment: Without weird hacks and stuff it's impossible. I also highly dis-recommend any attempts.

Comment: I can understand the situation like iframe-busting code etc. But why not to give the user the law to decide if he/she wants the toolbar or not. It is not like iframe-busting etc because they decide to install the toolbar so they want to have it over every website. They do not want to decide the owner of the website to show it or not

Comment: So for me it is very weird that using chrome extension I cannot promise to my users to have the functionality they expect (even if they decided to install extra soft) - strange.